# Handling id from autocomplete field

Tags: 7, ajax

I have an autocomplete field that selects id,text data from db table. I want to show the text in the field but need to put the selected id inside a hidden field so that, when the user submits the form, it is passed as form_values[] to _submit hook.
Which is the correct way to do it in D7?

Comment: So you have a autocomplete field that when selected set an ID. You then want to put that ID in a hidden field? I seem to be missing something...

Comment: Rather than hacking around with the javascript side of things in order to fill a hidden field, why not just do a lookup of the text value during `form_validate()` or `form_submit()`?

Answer (score -1):

I've run into the same topics and found a solution, check it here: [Autocomplete field - fill the selected id into another form element (eg. hidden field)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101099/autocomplete-field-fill-the-selected-id-into-another-form-element-eg-hidden)